# Error installing gcutil on cygwin

Tags: bash, curl, cygwin, gcutil

Following gcutil tutorial at https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/ here is a step of the download instructions :

[image]

However when I try this URL : "$ curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/insall_google_cloud_sdk.bash | bash"

I receive this error :

```
"$ curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/insall_google_cloud_sdk.bash |
 bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   869  100   869    0     0    562      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   679
bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
bash: line 1: `<!DOCTYPE html>'"
```

I've tried using http instead of https but receive this error :

```
$ curl http://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/insall_google_cloud_sdk.bash |
bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:03:50 --:--:--     0cu
rl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Is there a step that I'm missing ?

Comment: Did you observe that you have a missing `t` in `install` (you've spelt it `insall` which causes a 404)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be adding in an extra char, and also a newline there. The command is:

```
curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash | bash
```

There is no need for the `$` sign, that is just an indicator for the Cygwin bash shell. There should be no newlines at all in that string of commands (no newline after the `|`).